# Why does the y-combinator provide Turing equivalence?

Tags: clojure, lambda-calculus, turing-complete, y-combinator

[This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/222481/13382) says

1. Here is a basic y-combinator in lambda calculus:

   `Y f = (\x -> f (x x)) (\x -> f (x x))`

Ie Something like this in Clojure:

```
(defn Y [f]
  ((fn [x] (x x))
   (fn [x]
     (f (fn [& args]
          (apply (x x) args))))))

(def fac
     (fn [f]
       (fn [n]
         (if (zero? n) 1 (* n (f (dec n)))))))

(def fib
     (fn [f]
       (fn [n]
         (condp = n
           0 0
           1 1
           (+ (f (dec n))
              (f (dec (dec n))))))))
```

2. Here is another expression of the y-Combinator (step 2 of the argument)
3. We have encoded a Turing complete language (since we used the y-Combinator) (step 3 of the argument)

My question is: **Why does the y-combinator provide Turing equivalence?** It seems it was just an assumption of the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since having just λ already suffices for turing completeness, the Y Combinator is mere library code. It provides easy self-recursion.

The question as I read it, asks whether one could take away turing completeness from λ calculus, by elminiating self-application, to which the question obviously is no, since there is no way to reliably detecting self-application, short of actually running the calculus (the halting problem).

The argument just shows how to build Y without obvious self recursion and highlights the fact that Y is just the most condensed version of a whole family of patterns.

The real answer to the subset of lambda calculus that's not turing-complete is: total functions.

Answer (score 1):

First off. To be Turing Equivalent you don't need much. It's enough with `+`,`-`,`<`,`>` ,`[`, and `]` in BrainF**ck. If you were to remove features from a LISPy language and first take away all looping and recursive calls (Fortran didn't have recursion in the 60) would it still be Turing equivalent?

Yes. It's because you have both upward and downward higher order functions. With that you can make `Y` and get recursion. With recursion it's will be turing equivalent even if implementation didn't directly provide any looping.

Is it the Y combinator that enables it? Not really. You can make loops with `call-with-current-continuation` as well so I'd say it was higher order functions that enables it. If you do the exact same thing in a language that don't have higher order functions you cannot create `Y` and you cannot calculate all computable values.